# Can't find myself in reputation leagues

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

Is there a minimum total rep value you need in order to show up in reputation leagues? I cannot find myself in the Meta league of May, nor in the TeX one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not in the leagues if your reputation is below 200 hit points.

On the sidebar of the [Stack Exchange league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) for whatever site you're placing bets on you'll see this note:

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

Comment: Thanks, I had not spotted that. So I imagine that the people shown in the May leagues with <200 total rep are just the ones that later got up to 200.

Comment: heh, "hit points" - you must level up to be considered